# jQuery prevent flickering of child on hover

Tags: jquery

I'm having troubles when I hover an element and then hover an inside element. I don't know if its the best way to do what I'm trying to achieve. Here's my code:

My markup:

```
<div class="wrapper">  
   <div class="animation">  
     <a href="#" class="linked"><img src="#"/></a>  
     <h1 class="title hidden"><a href="#">blabla</a></h1>  
   </div>  
</div>
```

My js:

```
$('.animation a img').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().stop().fadeTo("medium", 1);  
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 0);  
    }, function(){  
        $(this).parent().next().stop().fadeTo("medium", 0);  
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", 1);   
    });
```

CSS:

```
    #wrapper {margin: 0 auto; width: 960px;}
    #hidden {display: none;}
    h1 a {bottom: 0; float: left; font-size: 1.5em; left: 0; position: absolute; width: 460px;}
    .linked {background: #666; float: left; height: 250px;}
```

The flickering starts when I hover the H1. Is there any way to disable or fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you hover the H1 seems like there's another animation and it's flicking the opacity from the parent img, I wanna stop that

Comment: could you add on http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GWHrK try to hover the red square and then hover the text, I don't wanna make the text go away.

Comment: Well, use @username to ping or alert someone. I have updated the link http://jsfiddle.net/GWHrK/1/ still i cannot understand your question. What do you want exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It this what you want http://jsfiddle.net/GWHrK/2/

```
$('.animation a img').hover(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().stop().fadeTo("medium", 1);  
        $(this).stop().fadeTo("fast", .5);  
});
```

Comment: Yes, something like that. But where's the hover out? On jsfiddle.net/GWHrK/1 when you hover the red square and hover the text, the red square fades to normal (which seems logical) but I don't want that. Hope that helps, so much thanks!

Comment: did u understand what I want? Tnx

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GWHrK/3/ I've updated the code. See it in action! Thanks anyway for your help :)